# Generating a random number with weighted probability - 'Distribution' gem

Tags: ruby, probability, distribution

I would like to create a random number generator, that generates a random decimal number:

- Greater than 0.0
- Less than 15.0
- Where the probability of that number being close to 2.0 is relatively high
- The probability of it being near 15.0 or very close to zero is very low

I'm terrifically poor at mathematics but my research seems to tell me I want to pull a random number from a Cumulative Distribution Function resembling a Fisher–Snedecor (F) pattern, a bit like this one:

http://cdn.app.compendium.com/uploads/user/458939f4-fe08-4dbc-b271-efca0f5a2682/742d7708-efd3-492c-abff-6044d78e3bbd/Image/6303a2314437d8fcf2f72d9a56b1293a/f_distribution_probability.png

I am using a Ruby gem called Distribution (https://github.com/sciruby/distribution) to try and achieve this. It looks like the right tool, but I'm having a terrible time trying to understand how to use it to achieve the desired outcome :( Any help please.

Comment: You will need to be more specific than "relatively high" probability of being close to 2.0 and "very low" probability of being close to 15.0...

Comment: Let's assume 'relatively high' means about 45%, and 'very low' means about 2.5% for now. I could then tune these variables to get the desired effect once I understand the function.

Comment: You're right that you want to identify an appropriate statistical distribution.  The problem with your question is that none of us have any basis for choosing between the many possible distributions (beta?  truncated F, chi-square, gamma?  triangular? piecewise uniform? etc., *ad nauseum*) that you could potentially use.  Have you any real data that would help determine what's a suitable distribution?  If so, your first step should be to use a stats package which can do distribution fitting to determine which distribution(s) would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take it back, there is no `rng` call for `F`. So, if you want to use `Distribution` gem, what I would propose is to use Chi<sup>2</sup> with 4 degrees of freedom.

Mode for Chi<sup>2</sup> with `k` degress of freedom is equal to `k-2`, so for 4 d.f. you'll get mode at 2, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). My Ruby is rusty, bear with me

```
require 'distribution'
normal = Distribution::Normal.rng(0)

g1 = normal.call
g2 = normal.call
g3 = normal.call
g4 = normal.call

chi2 = g1*g1 + g2*g2 + g3*g3 + g4*g4
```

UPDATE

You have to truncate it at 15, so if generated chi2 is greater than 15 just reject it and generate another one. Though I would say you won't see a lot of
value above 15, check graphs for PDF/CDF.

UPDATE II

And if you want to get samples from `F`, make generic Chi<sup>2</sup> generator for `d` degrees of freedom from code above, and just sample ratio of chi2, check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution)

```
chi2_d1 = DChi2(d1)
chi2_d2 = DChi2(d2)

f = (chi2_d1.call / d1) / (chi2_d2.call / d2)
```

UPDATE III

And, frankly, I don't see how you could get `F` distribution working for you. It is ok at `0`, but mode is equal to `(d1-2)/d1 * d2/(d2 + 2)`, and it is hard to see it equal to 2. Graph you provided has mode at about 1/3.

Comment: @pjs I was wrong wrt `F` sampling, there is no `rng` method, please check the update

Comment: You'll need a truncation loop to keep it bounded by 15.  Also note that you define `normal` but then call it with `normall` (two l's).

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your contributions to my question! All of the solutions put forward seem great and I know will help others. I have found the basic Chi2 solution fine for my particular problem but I look forward to experimenting with the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very crude, unscientific, non-mathy attempt at using the F-distribution with the parameters you gave in the F-function image (3 and 36).

First I calculate what F-value is needed for the CDF to be 0.975 (100% - 2.5% for the upper end of the range for your number 15):

To calculate that we can use the `p_value` method like so:

```
> F_15 = Distribution::F.p_value(0.975, 3, 36)
=> 3.5046846420861977
```

Next we simply use a multiplier so that when we calculate the CDF it will return the value 15 when the F-value is `F_15`.

```
> M = 15 / F_15
=> 4.27998565687528
```

And now we can generate random numbers with `rand`, which has a range of 0..1 like so:

```
[M * Distribution::F.p_value(rand, 3, 36), 15].min
```

The question is will this function be close to the number 2 with a 45% probability? Well..sort of. You need to pick the right parameters for the F-distribution to tweak the curve (or just adjust the multiplier `M`). But here's a sample with the parameters from your image:

```
0.step(0.99, 0.02).map { |n| 
  sprintf("%0.2f", M * Distribution::F.p_value(n, 3, 36)) 
}
```

Gives you:

```
["0.00", "0.26", "0.42", "0.57", "0.70", "0.83", "0.95", "1.07", 
 "1.20", "1.31", "1.43", "1.55", "1.67", "1.80", "1.92", "2.04", 
 "2.17", "2.30", "2.43", "2.56", "2.70", "2.84", "2.98", "3.13", 
 "3.28", "3.44", "3.60", "3.77", "3.95", "4.13", "4.32", "4.52", 
 "4.73", "4.95", "5.18", "5.43", "5.69", "5.97", "6.28", "6.61", 
 "6.97", "7.37", "7.81", "8.32", "8.90", "9.60", "10.45", "11.56",
 "13.14", "15.90"]
```

Comment: wrt `pick the right parameters for the F-distribution to tweak the curve` looks like no amount of tweaking will produce mode at 2. Check my update III

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Yes you have to truncate with `max`. Of course you can't get an exact 45% probability for "close to 2" because he had pre-chosen his parameters for the F-distribution in his example. As I said..this was a non-mathy solution. Just an example. We need the exact model of the probability distribution, but he didn't give one.

Comment: I think chi2 is a better choice. No way you could get peak for `F` close to 2

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Ok. That's good. I'll leave this up here anyway since it was a fun experiment to do. Maybe you can generate a similar table for the Chi2 distribution? Would be interesting to compare.

Comment: I don't think it is even possible for `F` mode to cross 1. It is `(d1-2)/d1 * d2/(d2 + 2)`, which makes it product of two less that 1 numbers.

Comment: I'll try, though last time I delat with Ruby was 8 (? more?)  years ago. Don't even have it installed...

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Hmm. It doesn't need to cross 1(?) since you can shift the distribution by multiplication like I did here. Or maybe I missed something? My multiplier is 4.3, which means if mode is 1 you'd get a peak at 4.3.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux d1 = 3, d2 = 36, M = 4.3, then you get ((d1-2)/d1 * d2/(d2 + 2)) * M => 1.36. Not quite 2, but close. So that's what I meant by "tweaking".

Comment: Ah, I see, yes with multiplier it might work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you know which distribution applies because of the nature of the data. If, for example, the random variable is the sum of independent, identical Bernouli (two-state) random variables, you know the former has a binomial distribution, which can be approximated by a Normal distribution. When, as here, that does not apply, you can use a continuous distribution, shaped by it's parameters, or simply use a discrete distribution. Others have made suggestions for using various continuous distributions, so I'll pass on some remarks about using a discrete distribution.

Suppose the discrete probability density function were the following:

```
pdf = [[0.5, 0.03], [1.0, 0.06], [1.5, 0.10], [ 2.0, 0.15], [2.5 , 0.15], [ 3.0, 0.10],
       [4.0, 0.11], [6.0, 0.14], [9.0, 0.10], [12.0, 0.03], [14.0, 0.02], [15.0, 0.01]] 


pdf.map(&:last).reduce(:+)
  #=> 1.0
```

This could be interpreted as there being a probability of 0.03 that the random variable will be less than 0.5, a 0.06 probability of the random variable being greater than or equal 0.5 and less than 1.0, and so on.

A discrete pdf might be constructed from historical data or by sampling, an advantage it has over using a continuous distribution. It can be made arbitrarily fine by increasing the numbers of intervals.

Next convert the pdf to a cumulative distribution function:

```
cum = 0.0
cdf = pdf.map { |k,v| [k, cum += v] }
  #=> [[0.5, 0.03], [1.0, 0.09], [1.5, 0.19], [2.0, 0.34], [2.5, 0.49], [3.0, 0.59],
  #    [4.0, 0.7], [6.0, 0.84], [9.0, 0.94], [12.0, 0.97], [14.0, 0.99], [15.0, 1.0]]
```

Now use [Kernel#rand](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) to generate pseudo random variates between `0.0` and `1.0` and use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to associate the random variate with a `cdf` key:

```
def rnd(cdf)
  r = rand
  cdf.find { |k,v| r < v }.first
end
```

Note that `cdf.find { |k,v| rand < v }.first` would produce erroneous results, since `rand` is executed for each key-value pair of `cdf`.

Let's try it 100,000 times, recording the relative frequencies

```
n = 100_000
inc = 1.0/n

n.times.with_object(Hash.new(0.0)) { |_, h| h[rnd(cdf)] += inc }.
  sort.
  map { |k,v| [k, v.round(5)] }.to_h
  #=> { 0.5=>0.03053, 1.0=>0.05992, 1.5=>0.10084, 2.0=>0.14959, 2.5=>0.15024,
  #     3.0=>0.10085, 4.0=>0.10946, 6.0=>0.13923, 9.0=>0.09919, 12.0=>0.03073, 
  #    14.0=>0.01931, 15.0=>0.01011}
```

Comment: Nice. From this I came to think of Bezier curves which would allow you to shape the distribution arbitrarily. But the problem then becomes how to find the inverse CFD value along the curve. That could become an expensive computation, depending on how accurate you need to be I guess.